# flutter bloc - get dynamic data in bloc from new page

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a `main` widget that nest `home` page widget and `setting` page widget. inside `setting`, will have a nest `pageView` widget

- main:

  - home
  - setting

    - pageView

I have a `main_bloc` to house some interactive data `selected_page_index`, to set the initialPage of the `pageView` when navigate to the `setting` page. Below are my code for the setting page:

```
class _SettingPageState extends State<SettingPage> {
  MainBloc _mainBloc;
  PageController facilityBookingPageviewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mainBloc = BlocProvider.of<MainBloc>(context);

    print(_mainBloc.selected_page_index); ///<-- this give me the correct value

    facilityBookingPageviewController = PageController(
      initialPage: _mainBloc.selected_page_index,
    );
  }
```

I can `print()` out the correct value in the `initState()`, but somehow the `initialPage` will only get the `_mainBloc.selected_page_index` original preset value.

I believe I done something wrong in terms of timing. How to properly do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `controller.currentPage` returns a double value. For example, when the page is being swiped the value goes from 1 to 2 gradually and does not instantly jump to 2. If use it jump second page directly. currentPage could use instead of initialPage if your `_mainBloc.selected_page_index` value is a double. Try this and let me know if it is worked for you